# UITabbarController + UINavigationController, detail view with UIToolbar instead of tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, uitoolbar

In my Main Window IB file I have a TabBarController and the first controller is a Navigation Controller. When I push my detail view (after pressing a cell in a table view) I want to push my detail view and display a tool bar instead of the tab bar. The problem is that when I try

```
 tabBar.hidden = visible;
```

in my detail view controller (viewDidLoad) the tabbar dissapears before the animation between the first view and the detail view is done.

What i want to achieve can be seen in the native photo app when pressing on one of the images from a gallery. There the tabbar moves out with the animation of the first view.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: would you mind to post your code? It is difficult to debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check out the 'hidesBottomBarWhenPushed' property on your detail's page subclass of UIViewController

either override this method

```
- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{
    return YES;
}
```

or i'm guessing this would work the same:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

as far as showing the toolbar try:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

and on the way out

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Here's some additional code from another answer that could be added to keep the toolbar visible as the user drills down.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816614/viewwilldisappear-determine-whether-view-controller-is-being-popped-or-is-showin

Comment: Great! But don't know why `self.navigationController.toolbar.hidden = YES;` not works! What's the difference between `toolbarHidden` and `toolbar.hidden`?

Comment: Have also to make following checkboxes checked in storyboard:
 1. Shows Toolbar attribute of Navigation Controller,
 2. Hidden attribute of that Toolbar.