# Where should I save a user's work when using a table with detail view pattern?

Tags: iphone

I've implemented workflow that uses a table view and a detail view with a navigation bar. I have been using the viewWillDisappear: message on the detail view to save the user's work, which I like because it makes sense intuitively, but it also gives the chance to set a cancel flag if the user wants to discard their work.

However, when I add the ability to take a picture to the workflow, it means that the viewWillDisappear: now is called both when the user goes back to the table and when going to the camera view. Is there a technique or method I can implement to make it so that the user's work is saved when going back to the table, but half finished work isn't saved when going into subviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a the detail view is being popped in the `viewWillDisappear:` method. The solution would be something similar to the answer to this question:

[viewWillDisappear: Determine whether view controller is being popped or is showing a sub-view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816614/viewwilldisappear-determine-whether-view-controller-is-being-popped-or-is-showin)