# Why is my ViewController being removed from NavigationController.ViewControllers collection

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am navigating between screens in my iOS application.

BaseView.NavigationController.ViewControllers

As I switch screens, I keep a reference to the previous screen in a static variable.

At some point, one of my items gets removed from BaseView.NavigationController.ViewControllers even though it's still a valid viewcontroller and IsLoaded is still set to True/YES.

When I use (pardon my C#/MonoTouch)

```
BaseView.NavigationController.PopToViewController(CurrentViewController,false);
```

to show it again, I get NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist. This is understandable because it's no longer in the ViewController collection.

The way I am switching screens is I am keeping a reference to he various screens and calling a common method to show the screen.  In that method I use this logic to determine if I should push or pop.

```
        if (CurrentViewController.IsViewLoaded)
        {

            BaseView.NavigationController.PopToViewController(CurrentViewController,false);
        }
        else
        {
            BaseView.NavigationController.PushViewController(CurrentViewController,true);
        }
```

My question is where did it go and why would it have been removed from ViewControllers collection and when it's StillLoaded=true/YES?

Comment: How are you switching screens?

Comment: Please see my most recent edit.  Described..

Comment: If you need more info, let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're using `NavigationController.PopToViewController(controller);` to navigate back to a certain view controller but keep a reference of the View Controllers that are popped from the navigation stack.

What I think is happening is because you're keeping a reference to these View Controllers, they're still in memory and thus the `IsViewLoaded` property is still `true` despite the View Controller not actually existing on the navigation stack.

Rather than using the `IsViewLoaded` property, you should check whether the View Controller exists in the `NavigationController.ViewControllers` array, if it does then Pop to it, if it doesn't then push it.

E.g.

```
if (BaseView.NavigationController.ViewControllers.Contains(CurrentViewController))
{
    BaseView.NavigationController.PopToViewController(CurrentViewController,false);
}
else
{
    BaseView.NavigationController.PushViewController(CurrentViewController,true);
}
```

**Edit**

So you mention you'd like a view to persist on the navigation stack. Well, using PopToViewController will remove **ALL** View Controllers between the TopViewController and the specified Controller.

In order to achieve what you're wanting, you could directly manipulate the `NavigationControllers.ViewControllers` array. Only problem with this is you'll lose the nice animations that the Push/Pop methods provide.

```
// Changes order of View Controllers currently in the stack. You can also add/remove 
// controllers using this method.
NavigationController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]{
          NavigationController.ViewControllers[1],
          NavigationController.ViewControllers[0],
          NavigationController.ViewControllers[3],
          NavigationController.ViewControllers[2]};
```

Comment: Interesting.  Let me try.  As a developer, do we have any control over what gets persisted and what doesn't?  Let's say I wanted certain screen to always be persisted, can I control this - or do I have to always check to see if they have been removed and create new instances if they have been?

Comment: If you're keeping a reference to the `UIViewController` then it is persisting, it just may not be on the navigation stack. So if you use the reference in the `PushViewController` call, then you're not necessarily creating a new instance when you push it onto the Navigation Stack.

Comment: I understand this.  My point is, as developers, can we control when ViewControllers get removed from the ViewControllers collection.  For example, I want a certain ViewController to always be in that collection and not removed automatically for whatever reason.

Comment: So, I mean - I want to keep something persisted on the navigation stack.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the animations.  Could I not manipulate the ViewControllers manually and then pop to the one I just added to the collection?  That should keep the animations?  I have yet to try this...  I will try later

Comment: I'm unsure what use case would require the functionality you describe (I'm not saying what you're doing is *wrong*, just, with the information provided I can't see why you're popping/pushing so often). Could you not present some of the views modally, so you're not changing the navigation stack so frequently?

Comment: See my other thread here if you want an idea for the use case.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436281/architectural-approach-to-handling-swiping-back-and-forth-between-many-screens-i

Think about how the Photos app works.  You swipe left and right continually to see a video or a photo.  In my case the content is a little more than a photo, so it's encapsulated in a view controller which I show.  I want to limit the creation of these for memory reasons.  If vc exists for specific page (id) pop it, otherwise create it.

Comment: What functionality specifically requires an entire VC to display the content? You can have one View controller, preload 3 views, the visible view, previous view and next view. Use a `UIPanGesutureRecogniser` to detect swipe, when enough of a pan is detected, animate the visible view off screen, animate the preloaded view onto the screen and lazy load the next view in the list. That's how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks Luke for your patience and your help.  I will look into your approach.  I'm just learning MonoTouch and iOS development, so there are a lot of concepts in iOS that I am still familiarizing myself with.

Comment: No worries, I was there once and know how awesome it is to have someone help, it's the least I could do.

Comment: So, as it makes sense to me.  My first screen is a menu.  That will have it's own View Controller.  If they click on "Menu A" it will go into my area of the app where I want to the user to be able to swipe left and right through a history of previous content.  This will have it's own ViewController as well, but will display a single view for each item navigated through and display and lazy load others as swiped in.  The views will conform to a common interface so that the ViewController can easily interact with a variety of views.  Does this make sense from an iOS architecture standpoint?