# How to check why viewWillDisappear: is called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to check if `viewWillDisappear:` is called because I am presenting another `UIViewController` as modal or not. Does anyone know if this is possible?

**UPDATE**

I want to know why it is being called. For example, if its being popped or if another `viewcontroller` is shown as modal. I need to differentiate the both.

Comment: Put nslog in viewWillDisappear. Exactly what you trying to do?

Comment: NSlog(@"ViewwillDisapper"); on that method.

Comment: Probably you do not want to know, when it is called in general but in a specific situation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816614/viewwilldisappear-determine-whether-view-controller-is-being-popped-or-is-showi could be helpful

Comment: I don't understand why this question is heavily downvoted. There are methods `isBeingDismissed` and `isMovingFromParentViewController` that are meant to be called from within `viewWillDisappear` to determine the reason for the appearence change, so testing for this situation seems a valid question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only a partial answer to your question, but have a look at ["Determining Why a View’s Appearance Changed"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html) in the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".

For example, you can call `[self isBeingDismissed]` from within `viewWillDisappear` to determine if the view controller was just dismissed (e.g. popped from the navigation stack).

Comment: Thank you so much! Calling [self isMovingFromParentViewController] found in your link did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a breakpoint in that method or do NSlog(@"ViewwillDisapper"); So, you can verify whether that method is calling or not.

Comment: It is default behaviour from Apple. it will called everytime when your view will disappear from iPhone screen.