# View controller lifecycle when swiping-to-pop from UINavigationController in iOS7

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, ios7, lifecycle

What is the impact of iOS 7's new swipe-to-pop gesture on the view controller lifecycle of `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

New in iOS 7 is a swipe-to-pop gesture in `UINavigationController`; you can swipe your finger from left-to-right to do what is normally done with the back button. The thing you have to watch for, is that the pop transition is *cancellable*.

### Tapping the back button still works the way you would expect it to:

1. User taps the back button
2. `viewWillDisappear` is called
3. `viewDidDisappear` is called
4. Popped controller is released

### Completing a swipe-to-pop is like tapping the back button

1. User begins to swipe from left-to-right
2. `viewWillDisappear` is called
3. User completes the swipe gesture
4. `viewDidDisappear` is called
5. Popped controller is released

### A cancelled swipe-to-pop works like this

1. User begins to swipe from left-to-right
2. `viewWillDisappear` is called
3. User aborts the swipe gesture (by reversing it, or by not dragging far enough to the right)
4. `viewWillAppear` is called
5. `viewDidAppear` is called

Update your expectations, and your view lifecycle methods accordingly.

Of note is the fact that `viewWillDisappear` is called in *all* cases, even if the user aborts the pop gesture. This may prove be a lie; if the swipe-to-pop gesture is aborted, your view isn't going to disappear, is it?

Like all of us, I strive to balance `addObserver/removeObserver` calls in my app to prevent crashes. I override the view controller lifecycle methods `viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear` to do the housekeeping, and maintain a `setupPerformed` flag to prevent observers from being added more than once during a view controller's lifetime. Moreover, I have relied on [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1816682/802047) to determine whether a view controller is about to be popped off a navigation controller's stack and subsequently released, so that I can know when precisely to tear down my observers.

iOS 7 has complicated this pattern. I can no longer rely on a view controller being torn down when `viewWillDisappear` is called. I have to expect that it might turn around, yell "just kidding," and proceed to call `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` all over again.

Comment: Yikes!  I remove my observers similarly.

Comment: Additionally, when you are in the middle of a swipe (a pan) then your UINavigationController will receive a call to -[UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:].  But when you cancel the swipe (the pan) by reversing it then you will *not* get a call to -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]

Comment: Another thing to note is the same behavior is applied to the (parent) view controller underneath the one you're popping from. The moment it peeks out, `viewWillAppear` is called, and if you cancel the pop, `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` are called respectively.

Comment: The core lesson is this: on iOS 7 or later, think of `viewWillAppear` as **`viewMightAppear`**, and `viewWillDisappear` as **`viewMightDisappear`**. You may not receive the corresponding `viewDid...` call after receiving the `viewWill...` call, for both the current view controller **and** the previous one in the stack.

Comment: thank you for the insight :) Is there a property for determining the percentage of the swipe in relation to the screenWidth or something similar? Or do I have to track it myself? I want to fade in the navigationBar.

Comment: Good question, @NickPodratz! You should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: I dont think Cancelled swipe works as u described anymore, it doesnt seems to get called on viewWillAppear

Comment: @Tj3n: Can you test this on every iOS version since iOS 6 (including the beta of iOS 10) and report back with the version number where the behavior changed?

Answer (score 6):

Great post!

As you say, you can no longer use the `viewWillDisappear` and the 'trick' as you described, but instead this works fine for me on iOS7 for **trapping the back button**.

```or-tag-here
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController == YES) {
    // Do the tidy up as before....
  }
}
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was slightly different. I'm overriding popViewControllerAnimated in a custom navigationController class. In the popViewControllerAnimated, I was able to detect a pop was occurring via drag when

```
self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible
```