# Swift: rootViewController never has its view[Will/Did]Disappear methods called

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, tvos

So I have a normal `UINavigationController` with its `rootViewController` set in the storyboard. Whenever I replace the navigation controller (don't ask why, but certain transitions in my app require the entire stack to be replaced with the new controller) using

```
var newController: UIViewController!
// newController is initiated at some point
...
if let navigationController = self.navigationController {
    navigationController.setViewControllers([newController])
}
```

And I can visually see the transition occur, but neither the viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear methods are called. When I subsequently replace the navigation controller stack they're called as expected. Is there something special about the root the prevents them from being called?

Comment: I think that's because the views are not actually disappearing when you switch root controller. Try calling `dismiss(animated: false)` on views that you're getting rid of.

Comment: Isn't dismiss meant for views that are presented modally?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Navigation controller works as a stack of controllers where child controllers go on top of the stack.

If you want to remove a deck of view controllers from a navigation controller, you should use the pop method on their root:

`navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

This will pop everything out of the stack and you will be able to replace the root with other controllers.

This other answer: [How to detect if view controller is being popped of from the navigation controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915249/how-to-detect-if-view-controller-is-being-popped-of-from-the-navigation-controll) expands on the different options you have to detect when your controller gets popped e.g. use `isMovingFromParentViewController`.