# Where to remove Notification observer in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am registering for Notifications in ViewDidLoad() in my Xamarin project. However I don't see any method where I can "Remove" the Observer. I need to execute something even when the View is not visible, so I can't give it in ViewWillAppear. Is there anything similar to "deinit" method.

Tried out "dispose" method in C#, but it didn't get called.

Even after doing a "PopViewController" the observer is still not getting unregistered. Not sure why it is not getting released from the memory even when the view controller is removed.

Comment: I think de initializer is best place

Comment: @SPatel What is the C# equivalent of de-initializer for Xamarin iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all subscription for events in **ViewDidLoad** and unsubscribing them would happen automatically from IOs. If you really feel to unsubscribe them, then do it in **Dispose** method.

Here's an example,

In the **ViewController**,

```
// Subscribing
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    _homeView.HomeButton.TouchUpInside += OnHomeButtonClicked;
}

// Unsubscribing
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    _secondView.SecondButton.TouchUpInside -= OnSecondButtonClicked;
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: `ViewDidUnload` has been deprecated since iOS 6

Comment: Yeah, and even then `ViewDidUnload` only got called when the device was running out of memory and needed to free some up

Comment: After @Nick ’s comment, I did some extensive research and figured out that in IOs 6+ this method is never called for the way views are handled under low-memory. And it’s really unnecessary to unsubscribe from listeners in the viewController either. If it’s really needed to be done, then it should be done in DidReceiveMemoryWarning overridden method. I have updated the answer accordingly!

Comment: `DidReceiveMemoryWarning` is not the place to do it either especially on newer hardware the amount of available memory may never become low enough for that method to get invoked.

Comment: I see Dispose is the place to unsubscribe listeners. And above all unsubscribing is not quite a necessity, IOs would take care of it automatically 

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you could override `ViewWillAppear` and/or `ViewDidDisappear` to add/remove it there.

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    // subscribe
}

public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
    // unsubscribe
}
```

Keep in mind `ViewDidDisappear` will be called when a new controller is pushed on top of your current controller and `ViewWillAppear` will get called again when that new controller is popped, which might not be suitable for whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: Exactly that is not suitable for what I am trying to achieve. In my case I have to do some operations regardless of when the view is visible or not. That is why I am registering it in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: At what point are you wanting to remove your observer, when the controller is no longer on the stack? You could also override `Dispose` and do it there or in a finalizer for your controller.

Comment: yes when the controller is not on the navigation stack. Tried with "dispose" method in C# but it didn't work. Any idea how to use that method ?

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967108/is-idisposable-dispose-called-automatically) a good example of how to use it. It's worth mentioning though even after you popped your controller it can still stick around in memory for a while before the garbage collector gets around to it.

Comment: Tried the solution (dispose pattern for a derived class that overrides Object.Finalize) given in the following link. Nothing is getting called when I pop the view controller. I have put Console logs to verify the same. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: It's possible it may be causing a memory leak so it's never getting disposed when gc runs. If you're popping from the same viewcontroller maybe you can add a local bool to check in ViewWillDisappear that you only set to true before popping so it only unsubscribes when popping and not when a new controllers is pushed on top.

Comment: I might do a "popToRoot" also from a different view controller. Is there any other way to deregister notification observer ? I guess the "deinit" is doing a similar thing in Swift, but not sure about C#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915249/how-to-detect-if-view-controller-is-being-popped-of-from-the-navigation-controll with that you might be able to also add a case to detect when poptoroot is called to still use ViewWillDisappear