# How does a parent ViewController know when its child gets popped off?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a navigation controller. I push view controllers onto the stack.

When one of the view controllers call:

`navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

How can the view controller before it know that its child just got popped? Is there a delegate or something?

Answer (score 0):

You could set `navigationController?.delegate` and use

```
navigationController(_:willShowViewController:animated:)]
```

Documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:). But that doesn't tell you what view controller is being popped.

Alternatively, you could use `ViewController.viewWillDisappear`, but that doesn't tell you why (is it popped or covered). There's an [answer already covering that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816614/viewwilldisappear-determine-whether-view-controller-is-being-popped-or-is-showi).