# Detect if you are going to a new view controller or previous

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation view controller, imagine this situation:

**My views contollers:** vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4

**My root navigation controller:** nc

And the stack of view controllers is like this:

**nc > vc1 > vc2 > vc3**

Now I am in vc3. I want to know how detect if you are going to a **previous view controller** (vc2) or you are moving to a **new one** (v4).

Guess this should be checked on viewWillDisappear method.

I am trying to check it with:

```
self.isMovingFromParentViewController()
```

But it only returns true if the previous vc is the navigation root.

Any further information you need just let me know, thanks.

**EDIT:**

*Pushing*

`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imageViewController, animated: true)`

*Going to previous view controller:*

I am not using dismiss, just swipping or pushing back button of the navigation.

(Swift 2.3)

Comment: "how detect if you are going to a previous view controller" How are you navigating from vc3?

Comment: Pushing to navigation controller.

Comment: Can you include the code here?

Comment: Yes, it's now there I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Things are trickier if you want to know when the navigation bar pops an item, you need `navigationBar:shouldPopItem:`. Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbardelegate/1624944-navigationbar?language=objc) out for more information. If you want to do something before the `pop`, the best way I can think of is to extend the `UINavigationController`.

```
@objc public protocol NavigationBarDelegate {
    @objc optional func navigationBarShouldPop() -> Bool }

extension UINavigationController: UINavigationBarDelegate  {

    public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        if viewControllers.count < (navigationBar.items?.count)! {
            // When it's being called twice
            return true
        }

        guard let vc = self.topViewController else { return true }
        var shouldPop = true

        if vc.responds(to: #selector(vc.navigationBarShouldPop)) {
            shouldPop = vc.navigationBarShouldPop()
        }

        if shouldPop {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // To fix the problem of back button disabled
                let dimmed = navigationBar.subviews.flatMap {$0.alpha < 1 ? $0 : nil}
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    dimmed.forEach { $0.alpha = 1 }
                })
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

And then if you want to do anything before your view controller get popped

```
class VC3: UIViewController, NavigationBarDelegate {
    func navigationBarShouldPop() -> Bool {
        // Do whatever you want here
        return true
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

Assuming that you are in `vc3` and of course you use `NavigationController` now. There should be 3 scenarios:

(1) You want to go back to `vc2`

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

(2) You want to navigate to a new view controller (`vc4`) and you use interface builder

```
let vc4 = VC4(nibName: "VC4View", bundle: nil)
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc4, animated: true)
```

(3) You want to pop to a view on stack but not the immediately previous one. E.g., `vc1`

```
// If the destination view controller is already on the stack, just pop to it
for item in (navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
    if item.isKind(of: VC1.self)  {
       _ = navigationController?.popToViewController(item, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: But with navigation controller you have the back button and you can swipe also to go back. I don't call dimiss anytime.

Comment: Are you saying you want to know when users click on `back` button?

Comment: This could be an option! But take in mind that I should know too when user swipe to go back.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have found this solution ([same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1816682/5288983)) it's in objective-C but I translate it to Swift and I have made one more modifications. Since I don't do dismiss view controller then if you are not pushing view controller then you are going back.

```
    if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
        if viewControllers.count > 1 && viewControllers[viewControllers.count-2] == self {
            print("New view controller was pushed")
        }
        else {
            print("View controller was popped")
        }

    }
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

If ViewDidLoad called, then you are pushing a new ViewController, else ViewController is already in the navigation controller stack and you are going to previous ViewController.