# Detect when ViewController has been presented by "popping" the previous VIewController in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

Consider the following navigation hierarchy:

> **NavigationContrller** -> **ViewController1** -> **ViewController2**

I'd like to detect when **ViewController1** is presented by going from **ViewController2**, i.e. by pressing the "Back" button on the NavigationController.

The method I'm interested is `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`. How can I check, whether the **ViewController1** has been presented by going forward (i.e. **NavigationController** -> **ViewController1**) or by going backward (i.e. **ViewController2** -> **ViewController1**)?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669562/detect-if-you-are-going-to-a-new-view-controller-or-previous. There's also an answer there that leads to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816614/viewwilldisappear-determine-whether-view-controller-is-being-popped-or-is-showi/1816682#1816682, which is basically what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the order of the controllers of your navigation stack in **viewWillAppear** like this:

```
      for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
                //  print("controller \(controller) at i \(i)") 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Bool` to keep track of the "push state":

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    private var isBeingPushed = true

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if isBeingPushed {
            print("forwards")
        } else {
            print("backwards")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        isBeingPushed = false
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    }

    override func didMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
        if parent == nil {
            isBeingPushed = true
        }
        super.didMove(toParent: parent)
    }

}
```